How can I filter users by their full name in Laravel when concatenating columns for a search?
$dataQuery = $dataQuery->where(function ($query) use ($fullname) {
    $nameParts = explode(' ', $fullname);

    if (count($nameParts) === 2) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($nameParts) {
            $q->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $nameParts[0] . '%')
              ->where('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $nameParts[1] . '%');
        });
    } else {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($fullname) {
            $q->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%')
              ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%');
        });
    }
});

I attempted to filter users based on a full name using a query that includes both firstname and lastname, as well as their concatenation. My goal was to allow users to search by their full name, where the search term could be matched against either firstname, lastname, or both combined

Use this code inside if and else condition:
->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname)"), 'like', "%$your_variable_name%");


You can modify your query to handle both the individual parts of the name and their concatenation. Here's a refined approach:
$dataQuery = $dataQuery->where(function ($query) use ($fullname) {
$nameParts = explode(' ', $fullname);

if (count($nameParts) === 2) {
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($nameParts) {
        $q->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $nameParts[0] . '%')
          ->where('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $nameParts[1] . '%');
    })->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname) like ?", ['%' . $fullname . '%']);
} else {
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($fullname) {
        $q->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%')
          ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%')
          ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname) like ?", ['%' . $fullname . '%']);
    });
}

});

try This with Where condition.
DB::raw("CONCAT('fname','lname') AS full_name"),'yourFilterVariable'
